# Função de encriptação ou ofuscamento com limite de tamanho de saída

Tags: oracle, pl-sql, oracle11g

Existe alguma Função Oracle de encriptação ou ofuscamento (padrão ou terceiros) que possa limitar o tamanho da saída?

Preciso ofuscar uma coluna menor que 20 char limitando a saída a 20 char.

Estou usando a seguinte `function` que gera uma saída de 32 Characters, a restrição vem de um sistema externo ao meu, não consegui negociar um tamanho maior da saída (entrada deles).

```sql
create or replace function md5 (valor varchar) return varchar2 is   
v_input varchar2(2000) := valor;   
hexkey varchar2(32) := null;   
begin   
hexkey := rawtohex(dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.md5(input => utl_raw.cast_to_raw(v_input)));  
return nvl(hexkey,'');   
end;
```

Comment: Já tentou com [ORA_HASH](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions107.htm)? Da uma olhada [aqui](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=27ee840e0cba5ea181b613f887fcb88d).

Comment: Parece que me atende , farei um teste, grato.

Comment: Boa tarde, pesquisei o DBMS_CRYPTO. Você pode dar uma estudada nos exemplos da documentação do pacote DBMS_CRYPTO. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_CRYPTO.html Note that hash values should be at least 128 bits in length to be considered secure.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode utilizar o Data Masking and Subsetting do Oracle Enterprise Manager para ocultar, criptografar e mesclar os seus dados. É possível criar regras especificando quem poderá ver os dados, como ele será exibido para quem não tem permissão. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue a documentação oficial que você pode utilizar para saber mais:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dmksb/intro.html#GUID-24B241AF-F77F-46ED-BEAE-3919BF1BBD80

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/late-answers/386161)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Coloquei a premiação aqui pois foi a resposta , mas usei a ideia do @Bruno Warmling